# How could Michael Knight have an evil twin brother?

Tags: knight-rider

Circa 1982, in the first episode of Knightrider, the detective is shot in the face, and given plastic surgury and a new identity, "Michael Knight." However, in Season 2, Episode 17, he faces his evil twin "Garthe Knight," who looks exactly like him.

**How can he have an identical evil twin brother for a false identity he assumed?**

Comment: His twin Garthe was shot in the face by an evil bullet, was given evil plastic surgery, and a new, evil, identity.

Comment: @Kalamane It's all coming together.

Comment: @Kalamane I thought he was shot by a good bullet.  As an evil twin, why would an evil bullet attack him?

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe how much Knight Rider information I just read, I hope this is a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Keen: the really sad part is, I could have answered this *from memory*. I probably should get out more...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Turns out it's actually the other way around, [Michael Knight](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Knight) looks like [Garthe Knight](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Garthe_Knight).  When [Michael Long](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Long) was wounded and [Wilton Knight](http://knight-rider.wikia.com/wiki/Wilton_Knight) put him through plastic surgery, Wilton made Michael Long look like his son, Garthe Knight.  Michael was then given his new identity as Michael Knight, with his modified face which looks exactly like Garthe.